# Excel 2019 shared (Legacy) spreadsheet user has mutually exclusive access for some reason?

Tags: microsoft-excel, shared-folders

There's a shared spreadsheet, stored on a mapped drive at work that users work on all at the same time, but when one of the users logs into it the rest are kicked out.

Is there a setting that causes this to happen?  Does it have something to do with the NTFS permissions of who shared the file first?

It's harming their productivity since they make changes locally and then they get kicked out.

Is there a setting I can change to fix this?

I've worked with the shared workbooks feature before in earlier versions of Excel on a team and I recall that we would all have to log out of the Spreadsheet when this happened and then open it back up again.  It almost sounds like a dead-lock to me where two threads both lock the file at the same time both wait for the file to become available for writing.

Is there a way to fix this?  They aren't keen on switching to OneDrive and their spreadsheets contain references to one another.

Comment: I'm told this has something to do with comments?  Something with the comments not being thread safe?

Comment: How did users login? Did you mean open the file at the same time? Did they get any message when open the Excel file?